# How to use timeit when timing a function

Tags: python, timeit

Let me start off by saying I know almost nothing about python but have to write a program in three different languages (already done in java and c++).

I need to be able to time the execution of a method a certain number of times and then print the time it took for the over-all execution time.

I.e.

I have function `A` (which is `performSearch(arrayTest)` where `arrayTest` is an array of known size). `A` is executed 10 times

I need to be able to time how long it took from before `A` was executed to after `A` was executed.

Answer (score 16):

You can read how to use timeit [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

And assuming you have a function called performSearch in the same file that your running timeit from the following would work.

```
import timeit

def performSearch(array):
    array.sort()


arrayTest = ["X"]*1000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(timeit.timeit("performSearch(arrayTest)","from __main__ import performSearch, arrayTest",number=10))
```

Which returns:

```
0.000162031766607
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error. here is the full code + what you said to use http://pastebin.com/71uXny9L

Comment: performSearch is your function not functionA

Comment: change `from __main__ import functionA, arrayTest` to `from __main__ import performSearch, arrayTest`

Comment: When I said functionA i was being generic, with the hope of not needing my entire code

Comment: I can understand that, all you need to do is change the bits in mine that say functionA to performSearch.

Answer (score 10):

You could do something like this:

```
import time

start = time.time()
A()
end = time.time()
print "Took %f ms" % ((end - start) * 1000.0)
```

Comment: This is a cleaner and nicer way of doing it while achieving practically the same result (at least in my case).

Comment: timeit uses a more precise counter, has functionality to do multiple measurements, and switches off garbage collection by default

Answer (score 3):

You can use below code as an example:

```
import timeit

def string_generator(size):
    return (size/8) * "ABCDEFGH"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #the below line runs the statement inside of '' for 100 times (number).
    print timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))',number=100)
    #the below line runs the statement inside of '' for 10 times (number) and repeat it 3 times.
    print timeit.repeat('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))',repeat=3,number=10)
    #if you would like to time a function, you can do it similar to below example:
    print timeit.timeit("string_generator(2**12)", setup="from __main__ import string_generator")
```

The results are :

```
0.00784516334534
[0.0009770393371582031, 0.00036597251892089844, 0.00037407875061035156]
0.414484977722
```

The unit for the results is second.
More examples are exist in python website. 
[enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)

Also you can use ipython. The same example is listed below.

```
In [25]: %timeit "-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))
```

The result is :

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.9 µs per loop
```

As you can see, the unit is macro second.

Answer (score 2):

if you want something simpler

```
import time
startMillis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print startMillis
time.sleep(5) # this is your function that takes time to execute
endMillis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
print endMillis

timeTaken = endMillis - startMillis
```

Answer (score 1):

yes well, just time it.

ex

```
total= 0
for i in range(1000):
    start= time.clock()
    function()
    end= time.clock()
    total += end-start
time= total/1000
```