# timing two algorithms (python) using timeit or time

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, audio, time, timeit

I am having some trouble using the time or timeit functions to determine the runtime of two algorithms within python. So far I have this

```
def normal(sound):
  for s in getSamples(sound):
    largest=max(0,getSampleValue(s))
    amplification = 32767.0/largest
  for s in getSamples(sound):
    louder = amplification*getSampleValue(s)
    setSampleValue(s,louder)

def onlyMax(sound):
  for s in getSamples(sound):
    value=getSampleValue(s)
    if value>0:
      setSampleValue(s,32767)
    if value<=0:
      setSampleValue(s,-32768)

import time
def timetwoalgorithms(sound):
    print time.time("normal(sound)","onlyMax(sound)")
```

The program should measure the time it takes to run each of the functions then output/print what the runtime of each program was.

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand the timeit or time function but some help would be appreciated, cant seem to find the answer within stack

Comment: I wrote an answer to this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19010935/1663352)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[time.time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) gives the current time. You want timeit.timeit.

```
print(timeit.timeit("normal(sound)"))
print(timeit.timeit("onlyMax(sound)"))
```

However, you cannot pass local variables to timeit ([how to pass parameters of a function when using timeit.Timer()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086430/how-to-pass-parameters-of-a-function-when-using-timeit-timer)), so you may have to simplify your function. You can either reimplement timeit:

```
def timeit(exec_s, globals={}, number=10000):
    t = time.time()
    for i in range(number):
        exec(exec_s, globals)
    return time.time() - t
```

and do

```
print(timeit("normal(sound)", locals()))
print(timeit("onlyMax(sound)", locals()))
```

or place the variables in the module namespace as per @Martijn Pieters answer.
Or, incorporating the timing loop into the main function:

```
def time2algorithms(sound, number=10000):
    t = time.time()
    for i in range(number):
        normal(sound)
    print(time.time() - t)
    t = time.time()
    for i in range(number):
        onlyMax(sound)
    print(time.time() - t)
```

Comment: Ok, so as I implement timeit into the function, should I be replacing exec_s with the funtion name? The error I receive is expecting a variable. If not, I don't think I have a handle on it

Comment: `exec_s` is a string to execute, just like for `timeit.timeit`. It can be any executable python, in the form of a string. So in your case, it is either `"normal(sound)"` or `"onlyMax(sound)"`. However, if you do not want to use a helper function, you can just replace `exec(exec_s, globals)` with `normal(sound)`. See edit.

Comment: This seems to work now, however again I am receiving a thread death while it tries to execute the range program through the time loop

Answer (score 1):

The [`time.time()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) does not take any arguments, because it is a function that simply returns the current time (in the form of seconds since a specific point in time, the UNIX epoch). You cannot use it to compare two function runtimes like that. You *could* use it to measure time passing by storing the value before running a function then comparing that to the `time.time()` value afterwards, but that's a poor method of measuring performance.

The [`timeit.timeit()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) *does* let you measure how much a test function takes, by repeatedly executing it and by making sure other factors that may impede accurate measurement are at least minimized. You can only test *one* such function at a time however.

To test one function, pass in Python source to run the function, and another function to set up the test. That setup should include importing the function:

```
timeit.timeit("normal(sound)", 'from __main__ import normal, sound')
```

Do this again for the *other* function and compare the outcomes against one another.

Take into account that the function will be executed *many times* (you can adjust how many), so if the function changes global state you'd have to reset that state each time. That'll change how you can measure the performance as well.