# How to call this function

Tags: python, timeit

How to measure the time of this code with timeit?(all functions have been defined)

```
    for i in range (1,10):
        bh = BinHeap()
        facc=[random.randrange(1,101,1) for _ in range (10+i)]
        bh.buildHeap(facc)
        print(bh.heapList)
        i=i+1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use timeit when timing a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010793/how-to-use-timeit-when-timing-a-function)

Comment: (you'll have to put that code in a function before)

Comment: Preface: this is not an answer to anything ... What do you expect the `i=i+1` to do on the last line -- Because if you think it is doing _something_, it probably isn't unless there's more code to follow that you're not showing...

Answer (score 0):

Try the documentation on [Profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)

```
python -m cProfile [-o output_file] [-s sort_order] myscript.py
```

and

```
cProfile.run('BinHeap()')
```

Comment: i want to know how to measure with timeit