# Measuring runtime best practices (Python)

Tags: python, runtime

I'm fairly new to evaluating algorithm complexity and my task is to measure real runtime for a few functions.

I have been using `time.process_time()`. Is this the best way to go about it?

- Is it accurate?
- Will runtime vary based on how "busy" my laptop is? (ex. I have other apps open)
- Are there other better methods?

Comment: Use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html) module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use timeit when timing a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010793/how-to-use-timeit-when-timing-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Option 1: Profiling Code to Learn about Overall Performance in Real-Life Scenarios***

This a great way of determining the impact of running your functions in real-life scenarios.

To learn more about your code performance, you can use [Profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script).

Run the following command to evaluate function performance:

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run('function()')
```

This gives you valuable information such as; Total call count, cumulative time, times for each function call, and call count for each function.

***Option 2: Investigating Spesific Function Call Duration***

This is a great method to learn about function runtime duration.

Using [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/):

```
from functools import wraps
from time import time

def timing(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        ts = time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time()
        print 'func:%r args:[%r, %r] took: %2.4f sec' % \
          (f.__name__, args, kw, te-ts)
        return result
    return wrap
```

Use it like this:

```
@timing
def function():
    <code>
```